# Color Coding in Puppet/Vagrant under Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, puppet, vagrant

When running Puppet/Vagrant and applying a manifest, the output is color coded, everything is cyan except errors which are magenta.

```
vagrant up
```

**Problem:** However on the Windows, theres no color coding, everything is white font on black background. Is there a way to turn on the color coding?

Comment: Probably it does not support windows console escape codes. But seriously, think of colorblind people (10% of men and 1% of women)! I absolutely hate when programs and sites use colors for almost everything and I simply cannot see anything they meant

Answer (score 0):

Check your TERM variable: "echo $TERM".

If you're using putty in Windows, "export TERM=putty".

Answer (score 0):

Setting env var ANSICON to any value helped in my case:
    `set ANSICON=blabla`